# How to exact match multi picklist field value with a string field in Apex

Tags: apex, multi-select

`user.City__c.contains(Sales.Contact__r.City__c)`

City is a field on user Object which is a multipicklist values with ; separated values, I want to compare city with city value from contact.

The problem with "contains" is if user has cities like "South San Francisco"; "San Francisco" & if city on the contact South San Francisco, it matches on both. I would like to do an exact match on South San Francisco instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the string into parts, then you can find the exact values:

```
 if(user.City__c.split(';').indexOf('San Francisco') != -1) {
   // Contains an exact match for San Francisco //
```

Note that you obviously need to check if the field/string is null before doing this, or you'll get a NullPointerException. In Winter '21 Apex, you can now write:

```
 Integer index = user.City__c?.split(';').indexOf('San Francisco');
 if(index != null && index != -1) {
   // Contains an exact match for San Francisco //
```

See the [Release Notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter21/release-notes/rn_apex_SafeNavigationOperator.htm) for more information on this feature.

Answer (score 0):

If you need exact match the you have to use = operator

1. user.City__c.equals(Sales.Contact__r.City__c);
2. Or if your condition is opposite , Sales.Contact__r.City__c.contains(user.City__c)

Comment: Equals will not work since the user multipicklist will have more than one values stored in it.